# Class name, HWNDs from PID

Tags: c++, c, winapi

how do I get class name and HWNDs of a process where only PID is known?

I need to set focus on a particular window of a process.

Comment: Note that user window classes are process-specific. "MyWindowClass" may be completely different or not exist in different processes.

Comment: And one way to check this is with something like Spy++

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to go directly from PID >> HWND since a PID can own multiple windows. You can however go the other way round.

- Enumerate all top-level windows ([EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- In the callback, get each window's associated PID ([GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and class name ([GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- If it's a match, set the focus ([SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))